# find $c$ and n0 in big $O$ notation problem

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science

So i know the definition of big $O$ notation.
But I can't find $n_0$ and $c$ (if $c$ and $n_0$ is given to me then i understand why this is true).
For example if i had:
$3n^2+5=O(n^2)$
$n_0=3$ and $c=4$
But how to find $c$ and $n_0$ only from $3n^2+5=O(n^2)$ ?
Thank you very very much
[image]

Comment: Please don't voted down the post.
You can explain to me what's wrong so I can improve it

Comment: It can be helpful to define any constants you introduce. I didn't know what $n_0$ and $c$ were meant to represent. I think I've figured it out, since Suhaib's edit made it clear that the 0 was a subscript.

Comment: the n0 (I tried to copy the mathjax code for better writing but it doesn't give me)
is represents the number from which the n^2  start to be faster.
I add a picture maybe it will help to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to note is that if you have one $c,n_0$ pair that works, you can increase $c$ or $n_0$ or both and it still works.  You just have to find one and justify it.  In the case of your example, with $f(n)=3n^2+5$ you need $c \gt 3$ or $f(n)$ will get too big.  Once you have $c \gt 3$ you just need $n_0$ large enough that the difference between $c$ and $3$ is enough to cover the $+5$ because $cn^2$ will be increasing faster than $3n^2+5$.  If you take $c=4$ you have an extra amount of $n^2$, which needs to be greater than $5$, so $n_0=3$ is enough.  I could equally well take $c=100, n_0=1000$ and it would work as well.

Comment: Thanks now I understand
I really appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm not sure I understand your notation, but I think what you want is a $n_0$ and $c$ such that $3n^2+5\leq cn^2$ for all $n\geq n_0$?

If so, then there isn't always a clear strategy to find $n_0$ and $c$. They will depend on the functions, and even then won't be unique, since big O notation gives qualitative estimates. But a sort of "approach'' to find $n_0$ and $c$ is as follows. If $f(n)=O(g(n))$, consider
$$\frac{|f(n)|}{|g(n)|}$$
for large $n$. Any upper bound for this can be your $c$. $n_0$ is a bit trickier. In your case you would get

$$3+\frac{5}{n^2}$$

which is bounded above by $c=4$ for any $n$ such that $5\leq n^2$, i.e. $n\geq 3$. We could also take $c=10$, and $n_0=1$, or $c=3.2$ and $n_0=200$.

Comment: I didn't understand. if |f(n)/g(n)| is our n how do you get in this case:
http://up419.siz.co.il/up2/zt5dyzmnknzm.png
That |f(n)/g(n)| is c?

Comment: $|f(n)|/|g(n)|$ needs to be bounded above by $c$ once $n$ is big enough. In this example, $|f(n)/g(n)|=|1/2 -3/n| \leq 1/2$ once $n>6$, so we can take $c=1/2$ and $n_0=6$

Comment: Thanks now I understand
I really appreciate the help